# Receive Antenna Design Consideration in Dual Antenna LF RFID System

Tags: antenna, communication, coil, rfid, near-field

I am working on constructing a loop antenna pair for an LF RFID application. The antenna is quite large (4' x 6').

I was able to successfully wind a transmit (Tx) antenna and tune it such that it delivers sufficient power so as to wirelessly power an LED in the center of the loop. It draws approximately 2.5 amps peak when tuned. I would imagine this would mean that the forward link budget of RFID communication with a tag is not an issue, as RFID tags typically have a minimum harvested power requirement of ~1uW.

The issue I am running into is the receive (Rx) antenna and what I presume is the reverse link path loss that is too high to properly detect backscatter radiation from the RFID tag. Admittedly, the antenna is most likely not optimized for the application (yet). It is approximately the same size as the transmit antenna although with a higher inductance value by about double. The tags can only be read around a few centimeters from the perimeter of the Rx antenna and I need them to be read in the center or as close as possible to it. I am not sure what needs to be done to make this antenna work better as there are not a lot of resources concerning LF bistatic near-field antenna systems. I also am not able to make many modifications to the long-range reader I am using; it is essentially a black box.

What design considerations need to be a made for an antenna pair such as this? I understand that the Rx antenna's SNR is most likely impacted by the Tx antenna. Should I tune it offset of the carrier frequency to better pick up backscatter? Is there a guideline for antenna characteristics (inductance, etc.) that will help improve the range of reads? Could this still be an issue with the Tx antenna?

Any advice or resources would be a huge help.

Comment: I have to admit I have a hard time following… you talk about a pair of antennas, do you mean the reader and the tag? There is only one induction loop in an RFID device (reader or tag). Also you mention your own device and then say you have a “black box” reader. Could you provide a diagram of all the components involved, which Ines you can change and which you can’t? Are you using standard RFID tags or are you designing your own? Also can you clarify if by LF you mean 125 kHz or 13.56 MHz (or something else entirely)?

Comment: @jcaron: sure, I can clarify. The pair of antennas I am referring to are a transmit antenna and a receive antenna. The long-range reader I am using has a topology that isolates the Tx and Rx signals so a circulator is not used for FDX tag protocols (I presume). The device you referred to, is this the LED I said I was able to light up? This is simply a quick test device I put together to measure field strength using a tuned inductor to resonance and rectifier to LED. I am using standard RFID tags and nothing can be changed except the antenna and feed. Also by LF I am specifically using 135kHz.